# CMake ARCHIVE_CREATE with relative paths

Tags: cmake

I have a project where I use CMake's ARCHIVE_CREATE, it correctly generates the '.zip' file, here is the code:

```
file(ARCHIVE_CREATE
  OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bundle.zip"
  PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/demo"
  FORMAT "zip"
  VERBOSE
)
```

Where `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/demo` dir has:

```bash
$ tree
.
├── blob
│   └── matrix.avif
└── scripts
    └── main.lua
```

However, the final directory structure is different, as shown in the image below:

[image]

My question is: how can I make sure the compressed file structure is exactly the same as the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up and ended with a small go program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    baseDir := os.Args[1]
    file, err := os.Create("bundle.zip")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w := zip.NewWriter(file)
    defer w.Close()

    walker := func(baseDir, path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        relPath, err := filepath.Rel(baseDir, path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()

        f, err := w.Create(relPath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(f, file)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }

    err = filepath.Walk(baseDir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        return walker(baseDir, path, info, err)
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

On CMake I run:

```
execute_process(COMMAND go run ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/pack.go ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/demo)
```